Problema al copiar página en oracle apex
Estoy tratando de copiar una página de una aplicación a otra en oracle apex pero tengo  problema ya que no me deja y me lanza el siguiete error
Error: Internal Error

Additional info: Contact your application administrator.
Details about this incident are available via debug id "315625".

Display location: ON_ERROR_PAGE

Association type:

Item name:

Region id:

Column alias:

Row:

Model instance id:

Model record id:

Internal error: true

Common runtime error: false

APEX error code: APEX.ERROR.INTERNAL

SQL code: -6502

SQL error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_IMP_PAGE", line 5130
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 5860
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 5860
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 6088
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 6088

Backtrace: ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_IMP_PAGE", line 5130
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 5860
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 5860
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 6088
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 6088
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_COPY_PAGE", line 8023

Statement:

Component: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS copy page from another app (203816820266708299)



lo que puedes hacer en ese caso es copiar los elementos a otra pagina, para dividirla y luego copias las 2 y las vuelves a unir

osea copiar de elemento por elemento?

si seria lo mas correcto porque la pagina tiene o muchos elementos o querys demaciado largas lo que suelo hacer es dividirla en 2 para no copiar elemento por elemento

y que tan accesible es exportarla y luego importarla?
